# Google Glass hides my app from menu after firmware update on 18/Apr/2014

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

On 18/Apr/2014, Google Glass started firmware update automatically when I booted up Google Glass. 
After the firmware update, my app which I've been making with GDK disappears from menu and I couldn't launch my app from voice command.
I reinstall the app, but it's the same. 
I could uninstall the app by ADB, so the APK is there and installed in Google Glass, but seems Google Glass hides my app's command from the menu.
Did anyone has the same experience ? Is there any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the XE16 release note. You need to request the development permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission
     android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />
```

https://developers.google.com/glass/release-notes#xe16
https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/starting-glassware#unlisted_commands